# Fragment layout help needed

Tags: android, android-layout

This is probably an easy one, but i just cant seem to work out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm writing an android app (java) and i'm populating a list in a fragment from an api call.

At first the fragment was displaying full screen rather than as part of the activity so i placed the list into a layout (shown below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ProvinceFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Heading"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menuHomeButton"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="First bit"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menuChangeProvButton"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Second bit"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/listLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

This renders the list as part of the original activity but I cant seem to get the list to expand to fill the available screen space and then the page to scroll.
The list is there and scrollable, but its only 1 list item tall.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

*Edit

This is the layout of the activity that I'm trying to load the fragment into

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menuButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/bars" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/fml_logo1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--This should contain the fragment-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<!--MENU-->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/sideMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#aa000000"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menuCloseButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/bars" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Menu"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menuHomeButton"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Home"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menuChangeProvButton"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Change GL/Province"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>'
```

I'm really new to this so really appreciate the help.

Comment: You set its height to 0. Care to set it to ```wrap_content``` or ```match_parent``` instead?

Comment: That does work and makes the listview expand and scroll, however it makes the fragment go full screen and I lose the activity I was in (and therefore the header and navigation)

Comment: Could it be the way I'm inflating the listview from the ListViewAdapter?
Could it be the way I'm inflating the listview in the ListViewAdapter?
    
    'View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.prov_list_items, null, true);'

Comment: What d'you mean "lose the activity"? How and where this fragment is shown?

Comment: So, I have an activity that has a nav drawer and and a header.
The menu loads the fragments into a Frame in the layout. this seems to work ok.
When i change the height of the ListView to match_parent it makes the fragment go full screen.
I've obviously got a problem with the layout, but i cant quite see where it is.
Sorry, I'm new to this.
I'll edit the question to include the code for the main layout that its being loaded into.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the fragment to be drawn above all the activity content you'd need to place the container of the fragment below all the other layouts so it gets drawn above them like so in your `Activity` Layout.

```
...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
<FragmentContainerView  
    android:id="@+id/your_fragment_container"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    ..... />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort out the issue by scrapping the layout and starting from scratch.
Still not quite sure what it was that I'd done wrong initially, but thanks for the help.